# I want to post a php variable from a form

Tags: php, post

I have a php variable "echo $id". Now I want to use the $_POST method to post the variable. I just want to know how to do this for a variable because $_POST[$id] does not work?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to get acquainted with some concepts first.

Comment: say what?? Post where ? variable echo $id ??

Comment: What do you mean by `posting the variable`? $_POST gets data out of a form **into** a variable. And it's not a method, `$_POST` is a variable itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the method $_POST you must be posting to something.

My suggestion to you is to create a form, then have the form going to the file you wish to post to:

So something like this:

```
echo '<form action  = "fileToPostTo.php" method = "post">
<input type = "text" hidden value = "'.$id.'" />
</form>';
```

And then submit the form when the document loads through jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding a basic concept here.

The `$_POST` super global is used to receive input (in the form of a POST request) **from the user**. While it is possible to set variables in it, **you shouldn't**.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not make sense. If you have an HTML form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="something" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then you get the variable `$_POST['something']` with whatever the user typed in the text box.

On its own, `$_POST` is just a variable like any other. You can assign to it `$_POST['test'] = 123;`, you can delete from it `unset($_POST['test']);`, you can even make it something other than an array `$_POST = "Hello, world";`, it just happens to be pre-populated with form data, if any.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `$_POST['id'] = $id` (then You will have it in `$_POST['id']` variable (but You shouldn't do it :P).

Or You can send `$id` by form. Like example:

```
<form action="/pageToPOST.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" value="<?=$id ?>" name="id" />
  <input type="submit" name="" value="submit it!" />
</form>
```

And You'll have `$_POST['id']` on `http://yourdomainname.com/pageToPOST.php` page

Answer (score 0):

you can get and pass the value without page load and form.

```
 <input type="text" name="something" id="something" />
 <input type="button" value="ok" onclick="value();"/>
 function value()
 {
 var something=$("#something").val();
 var dataparam="oper=show&something="+something;
  $.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url:"yourphpname.pnp",//this is very important.
      data:dataparam,
      success:function(data)
   {
   alert(data);
   }
   });
    }
     $oper =(isset( $_REQUEST['oper'])) ?  $_REQUEST['oper'] : '';
          if($oper == "show" and $oper != '')
          {
         $something=$_REQUEST['something']
         echo $something;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is assign a value submitted to your script using the POST method, to your $id variable. Something like:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```