# how to use $_POST to post a php variable

Tags: php

I have a php variable "echo $id". Now I want to use the $_POST method to post the variable. I just want to know how to do this for a variable because $_POST[$id] does not work? I want the $id to be posted from the form into another page.

Below is my function where the $id is in:

```
function id_generator(){ 

          $id = ""; 
          $a = array( "A" , "B"); 

      for( $i = 0 ; $i < 3 ; $i++ ){ $r = rand( 0 , 25 );
       $id .= $a[ $r ]; 

   }

   return $id;
}
```

Below is the form:

```
         <form action="QandATable.php" method="post" id="sessionForm">
         <p><strong>1: Your Session ID: </strong><?php echo $id; ?></p>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to post a php variable from a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545082/i-want-to-post-a-php-variable-from-a-form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the id into a form input field.  For example, to put it in a hidden input:

```
<form action="QandATable.php" method="post" id="sessionForm">
     <p><strong>1: Your Session ID: </strong><?php echo $id; ?></p>
     <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id; ?>' />
</form>
```

Then after the user clicks a submit button (which you will also need to add to the form), in QandATable.php you can just go

```
$id = $_POST["id"]
```

to get the id.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` variable keeps values passed via POST method. But in your code I don't see any fields in form that can handle this value. You should create `input`, `select` or `textarea` inside `<form>` tag. Then after submit `$_POST` will be filled with values of this fields. Key in `$_POST` array will come from `name` attribute and value will be value of field. You probably want to use `$_SESSION` variable in this case. With `$_SESSION` variable is remembered on server.

```
$_SESSION['id'] = id_generator(); // to set
echo $_SESSION['id']; // to use
```